# Docker Run and variable substitution

Tags: bash, docker, environment-variables

I have a variable in a script called `image_name`

```
image_name="my-app"
```

And I am attempting to pass this variable to a docker container as seen below:

```
docker build -t $image_name .
docker run --rm --name $image_name -e "app_dir=${image_name}" $image_name
```

But this variable is not set and is blank within the context of the docker build

This is a snippet from the Dockerfile below:

```
....

RUN     echo dir is $app_dir

....
```

This is a snippet of the build output below:

```
....

Step 2 : RUN echo dir is $app_dir
---> Running in db93a939d701
dir is
---> c9f5e2a657d5
Removing intermediate container db93a939d701

....
```

Anyone know how to do the variable substitution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that you are using the variable inside the `Dockerfile`. That variable will be evaluated at build time (`docker build`), so you need to pass its value at that moment. That can be achieved with the `--build-arg` param.

Changing your example, it would be:

```
docker build --build-arg app_dir=${image_name} -t $image_name .
docker run --rm --name $image_name $image_name
```

Answer (score 1):

This is achievable using the `build-arg` parameter of the `docker build` command

See: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6822#issuecomment-168170031 for an example

Comment: Don't forget to also double-quote your expansions.

Comment: Could you post an example? I'm still learning bash scripting myself

Comment: "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and _every_ expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use 'single quotes' for code or literal $'s: `'Costs $5 
                US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes , http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words .